# iPhone Orientation / phonegap

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, cordova

I have a phonegap application made for ios. What I would like it to do is have my orientation locked in the vertical mode, except when I launch a vimeo video in the native ios player. Currently, when I lock into vertical mode the player also plays vertically and does not rotate. Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Ios 5
phonegap (cordova) 1.8.1
Jquery
Jquery Mobile

Comment: have you tried this plugin, might help you - https://github.com/acti0nm4n/Phonegap-Orientation-iOS

Comment: it is using phonegap and not cordova so might require some changes

Comment: Need all the help I can get on this one...it appears that that doesn't work with cordova. Have any other options that would work with cordova?

Comment: actually i changed the plugin to work with cordova 1.7.0 but some of the things are not working as iOS api related to orientation is changed. I am trying to finish and put the code in github and update you.

Comment: That would be awesome, for planning purposes, how log do you think that will take you?

Comment: Also, if you write it for cordova 1.7 will it work with 1.8...I'm on 1.8

Comment: most of my other samples in which i have used 1.7 have also worked with 1.8, so i will finish it for 1.7 and then test for 1.8, besides it will be a simple plugin so i think version change should not affect now.

Comment: Any chance you had time to convert this over to cordova 1.8 yet? Just trying to get my app out the door and this is a crucial piece. Let me know, thanks!

Comment: sorry i tried several methods but could not make it work perfectly and then got busy in other work. i will again check and update you and also put the code in github if someone can help

Comment: The quick and dirty solution would be to write an "1-liner" plugin which enables you to turn orientation changes on and of out of your javascript code. Unlock on video play, lock again afterwards.